# Fill a form with XML (Java)

Tags: java, xml

I have a form and a XML, and i would like to fill the form with the XML datas.

The XML file have a structure like that:

```
<Patient >

  <General>
    <Name>Peter</Name>
    <DataofBirth>6/Nov/2010</ DataofBirth >
    <Sex>2</Sex>
  </General>

  <MedicalData>
    <Weight>100</ Weight >
    <Height>170</ Height >
  </ MedicalData >

</ Patient >
```

And when I can’t access at the data of the second tag `<MedicalData>`.

I'm programing in Java and use Jdom to create the XML file.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, you say "and when I can’t access at the data of the second tag <MedicalData>."  What are you trying, and what problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use [**XStream**](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)
2.create a class from your XML data structure
3.obtain collection of Objects of that class from XML
4. then just use them simply.

[Here is quick start](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)