# select a radio button in a group

Tags: java, xml, radio-button

I’m programming in Java and I have an xml file and a form.

How can I use the data of the xml file to select a radio button in a group?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: You should really add some more details to your question! What kind of XML? What radio buttons? Are you using Swing? What is the content of the XML file and how does it relate to the radio button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill a form with XML (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184008/fill-a-form-with-xml-java) - this sounds familiar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Selenium, you can generate clicks, enter data into fields in a form, and screen scrape data from a page, plus more. I just 'found' this and find it totally indispensable.

[Link to Selenium site](http://seleniumhq.org/)